# Java synchronized counter - what about get()?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, counter

It's known that simple `x++` is not an atomic operation, but in fact is read-increment-write operation. That is why it should be synchronized. But what about `get()`? I have read it should be synchronized too, but could someone explain me why? To avoid memory consistency errors by introducing `happens-before` relationship?
What about a situation when `get()` is called very often by multiple threads and the value is rarely changed. Isn't `synchronized get()` slowing them down? Are there any other ways to achieve synchronization in that scenario (not using AtomicInteger)? Would `volatile` keyword work here?

```
public class Counter {
    private int value;

    public synchronized int get() { return value; }
    public synchronized int increment() { return ++value; }
    public synchronized int decrement() { return --value; }
}
```

Thanks!

edit:

I would like to make myself clear. By using `volatile` I meant introducing that keyword and removing `synchronized` in `get()` method. I was wondering if it will make it thread-safe but also more efficient if many threads are reading the value and one is rarely changing it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Are there any other ways to achieve synchronization in that scenario (not using AtomicInteger)?

First off, you should be using [`AtomicInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) if you can.  I'm not sure why you would not use it.

> Would volatile keyword work here?

Yes except not for the `++`. `AtomicInteger` provides a safe increment without locking.  If you want to roll your own (for some crazy reason) then you will need the blocking or you need to duplicate the `AtomicInteger` internal spin mechanisms.

> But what about get()? I have read it should be synchronized too, but could someone explain me why?

`AtomicInteger` wraps a `volatile int` to provide its functionality.  When you access the `volatile` field you cross a memory barrier on the `get()` as well.   You *need* to cross that memory barrier to ensure that if another thread has updated the value, the thread calling the `get()` sees the update.  Otherwise, a thread could be working with a outdated value.

Comment: I was just trying to achieve same behavior as with AtomicInteger not using it :P

By using `volatile` I meant introducing that keyword and removing `synchronized` in `get()` method. I was wondering if it will make it thread-safe but also more efficient if many threads read the value and one is rarely changing it.

Comment: Yes @JakubKrawczyk, that would work.  Are you trying to be faster than `AtomicInteger`?  Why not use that class?  If this is for efficiency then you are doing the definition of premature optimization.

Comment: I'm not trying to implement my own `AtomicInteger` :) I was just trying to understand synchronization in that matter. I assumed that obvious answer would be "use `AtomicInteger`" and I wanted to avoid it :P It didn't work ;) Thanks!

Comment: @Gray Is it possible that thread scheduler can change the state of a thread which has acquired the lock and is executing the synchronized block to say wait so that other thread can acquire the lock?

Comment: Either a thread has a lock or not. A thread can have the lock and get unscheduled of course but a thread will not have a lock taken away from it if that is what you are implying @YugSingh.

Comment: @Gray since thread can get unscheduled then in the code in question even though get() may be synchronized  but that doesn't ensure that each thread gets the updated value because it may be the case that when set() is called the scheduler may unschedule thread1 and it is still in the middle of read-update-write operation that is let's assume it has performed update but not write. So now there is another thread2 which calls get and it will see the old value. To avoid this we need to declare value instance var volatile. That will ensure that thread1 performs complete oper. due to happens-before.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand this. synchronized has implied memory barriers. You don't need both volatile and synchronized typically. If the get thread is unscheduled with the lock then the set method will block until the thread comes back and releases the lock. If another thread calls get at the same time then there is a race condition around whether the setter will get the lock before the thread2 getter (typically it is FIFO) but there is no way that 2 threads can be in the middle of the get and set methods at the same time if both methods are synchronized. @YugSingh

Comment: @Gray sorry for the ambiguity. But I got the point from your comment above. I was not aware that `set method will block until the thread comes back`. But I didn't understand the cause of race condition. Since both set and get are synchronized on `this` and as you mentioned set will block until thread comes back there should be no race condition.

Comment: You provided a scenario with 3 threads.  #1 locked inside of get(), #2 calling set(), and #3 also calling get().  I was just commenting that whether or not #3 sees #2's update to the value depends on which one gets the lock first.  That's a race.  synchronized doesn't _stop_ the races, it just protects against data corruption or improper application behavior. @YugSingh

Comment: @Gray Thanks for the comments. What I understood is that thread scheduler can unschedule the thread which has the lock. Once it is unscheduled the other threads can try to get the lock which results in the race.

Answer (score 1):

If you repeatedly read a non-volatile value, the JVM can cache the value in a register can you might not see any changes.

The way to avoid this is to make the value volatile.

However if performance is a concern, use AtomicInteger which is lock-less.

Comment: I mean the CPU's register, but you get a similar problem at the cache level as well.

Comment: "Might not see any changes" is a hellavalot more clear than the Java docs saying "synchronized establishes a happens-before relationship".  Sometimes you don't care about order if the getting side is polling anyway but you certainly do care about getting the change eventually. It would appear from your comment there is a risk that the getting side will never see the change.

Answer (score 0):

> But what about get()? I have read it should be synchronized too, but
>   could someone explain me why?

Suppose if `get()` was not synchronized, then any Thread would be able to invoke it while a Thread is executing a `set()` operation..

Now, if suppose, Thread B is performing set() operation to set the value of a field `a` to 5. Now, suppose two thread are reading the value a.. One thread reads before the set operation is completed, and other thread reads after set operation..

So, Both Threads have different values.. Thus they have an inconsistent state of field `a`.

Now suppose that `get()` method is syncrhonized.. Then if a thread is setting a value.. Then no thread can invoke `get()` operation unless the `set()` operation is complete.. So every Thread will get the same value..

Comment: Some applications don't need every thread to see the same value ASAP as long as they see the correct value eventually.  @Peter Lawreys comment suggests there is still a risk for such applications.

Comment: Is it possible that thread scheduler can change the state of a thread which has acquired the lock and is executing the synchronized block to say wait so that other thread can acquire the lock?

Answer (score 0):

> But what about get()? I have read it should be synchronized too, but could someone explain me why? To avoid memory consistency errors by introducing happens-before relationship?

Yes, it should be synchronized. If it is not it may be using a stale value, just as the increment/decrement would.

> What about a situation when get() is called very often by multiple threads and the value is rarely changed. Isn't synchronized get() slowing them down?

Uncontested locks are very cheap. Even for concurrent gets, the cost may not affect overall performance much. `volatile` works here, but not using `AtomicInteger` for peformance reasons may not be necessary.

> Are there any other ways to achieve synchronization in that scenario (not using AtomicInteger)? Would volatile keyword work here?

Yes, I believe it would.