# Intrinsic locks and Synchronization in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

As per Oracle docs for [Intrinsic Locks and Synchronization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html) :

> Intrinsic locks play a role in both aspects of synchronization:
>   enforcing exclusive access to an object's state and establishing
>   happens-before relationships that are essential to visibility.

My question is:

what does **happens-before relationships** here means in synchronization context? Does this mean that once a thread executes a synchronized block all the changes are flushed to main memory before other thread comes and reacquire the lock?

Also I have another question:

Suppose **thread1** has acquired the lock and is executing the synchronized block.

Is it possible for **JVM/thread scheduler** to force the **thread1** to another state say **wait** such that it will release the lock and another thread say **thread2** will acquire the lock? Now after some time thread1 can again go into **running state** and start from where it lost the lock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what does happens-before relationships here means in synchronization
>   context?

This relationship is simply a [guarantee](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/memconsist.html) that memory writes by one specific statement are visible to another specific statement. In this case, it means when you write some thing in the synchronized block, then other threads which enter the synchronized block will notice this change.

> Is it possible for JVM/thread scheduler to force the thread1 to
>   another state say wait such that it will release the lock and another
>   thread say thread2 will acquire the lock?

No, while the thread can release the lock by calling `wait`.

Comment: Is it possible that thread scheduler can unschedule the thread holding the lock?

Comment: I have asked the same question in comments of some other question related to multithreading and the answerer mentioned that it's possible which lead to my confusion regarding the same. I myself think it shouldn't be allowed as it might cause a `visibility` issue say in `read-update-write` operations. A Thread having the lock may have read and updated the var. and before it could write it may be unscheduled and it has to release the lock. Now other thread can acquire the lock and perform the read-update-write operation. Could you pls let me know if my reasoning is correct? Thanks.

Comment: The JVM guarantees the code in `synchronized` block mutual-exclusion, unless the thread calls `wait` to give the lock up... I do not actually know what do you mean by `unschedule`... Maybe you can post the link to *some other question related to multithreading* and I will check it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12731450/java-synchronized-counter-what-about-get/12731467?noredirect=1#comment94988046_12731467

Comment: In the above link I am referring to this statement `A thread can have the lock and get unscheduled of course`

Comment: @YugSingh I know what you are talking now. Yes, it could be unscheduled. But this does not mean other threads can access the code. The other threads which try to execute the synchrinized block will get blocked! Until this thread get scheduled and finish the synchronized block.